# Spacing between UITableViewCell and UITableViewRowAction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

Is it is possible to add spacing between the **UITableViewCell** and **UITableViewRowAction** and is possible to add corner radius to **UITableViewRowAction** as per attached UI.
[Find attachment Here!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rui5z.png)

Answer (score 0):

Directly you cannot add space between UITableViewCells.You should use some tricky points to achieve this.I think you can get an idea from this.

[image: Some Points]

Comment: Is it possible to add UIView inside UITableViewRowAction?

Comment: You can add image inside UITableViewRowAction, but not UIView.

Answer (score 0):

You can access that view like that:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if let deleteView = tableView.subviews
        .first(where: { $0.classForCoder.description() == "UISwipeActionPullView" }) {
        deleteView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    }
}
```

PS! Might not be future proof, if apple changes anything. Maybe helps you.